# Upgrade Path: Non Cordova App - Cordova App

Tags: android, ios, cordova, windows-phone-8

Here is the situation:

- app currently in production packaged using home brewed packager
- new packager has been created that uses cordova

Is there a way I can fix the upgrade path so that when I update from an old version of the app packaged using the old packager to the new version of the app packaged with cordova it will recognise that the new app is an upgrade and not a completely different app?

Right now installing the new version of the app just sticks it alongside the old app with the same name.

Thanks.

Comment: you have to use the same bundle identifier (or package name on android), if it's the same the old app will be removed when you install the new version

Comment: ah yeah, silly me the person who had written the original packager had a different convention for the id. That solved it, if you put that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use the same bundle identifier (ios) or package name (android), if it's the same the old app will be removed when you install the new version